# How can I manipulate a single box in PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[I am trying to multiply the sum(row 31) of a specific column and have it show up in row 32. as the only item in the new row. What is the best way to go about this? Thank you!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmAqu.png)

'''Askins.append(Askins.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)'''

This line gives the total. Now in the next line I am trying to take that total and the specific calculation I am trying to do is 45656.91/70000*10000. I am trying to figure out what the next step would be.

Comment: Your question should contain your code as text, not as an image or link, so that it can be viewed/copied/pasted/etc. That said, look at the difference between your lines (parentheses especially): `...sum()/7000` vs `...sum(/7000...)`

Comment: please add your code in order to better result.